# Use of "3D" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [3d](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3d) tag is currently used for 12 questions, of them 6 deal with **3D displays or games running on such displays**. I think it's good if we limit this tag to only be used for such topics, remove it from the other questions, and update the tag wiki appropriately; since otherwise I don't see a lot of use for it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with this - with the 3D technology for gaming on the wise, the 3D tag should apply to games with 3D effects, not games that are in "3D" (Zelda Wind Waker, Call of Duty, Rayman 2, et cetera).

That said...what would be the proper term for games previously referred to as  in "3D" (wind waker, raymen et cetera)? I'm not even sure what I would call them to be perfectly honest :/

Comment: Well, Zelda Wind Waker uses a form of cel-shading, and I'd argue that games that what was previously called "3d graphics" are just using CG. That's the distinction made in the movie industry.

Comment: Those are 3D too, you just can't see them in 3D. The main problem is that you don't just tag every question with every tag that applies to the game. It'd be hard to actually find a question that's about the in-game 3D itself, so the tag is best reserved for the 3D output devices and their setup/troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

-If the question discusses the 3D stereoscopic features of the game, then I'd tag it with `3D-Stereoscopic`.  Such a tag would be easily found by someone typing 3D but be clearly specific to stereoscopic.

-If the subject of the question is the game using 3D models, then I'd say the tag is appropriate.  Or maybe one named less ambiguously.  Perhaps `3D-Graphics` or `3D-Rendered`.

**-If the subject of the question is not dealing with the 3D aspect of the game, then it is inappropriate.  The tags should reflect the subject of the question.  The tags are not meant to describe the game.** The tags are for categorizing questions, not games.

There will certainly continue to be misusage of the tags, but at least for those who want to use them properly, they will have less ambiguous options to do so with.

Comment: It appears that this has already been done using the [tag:stereo-3d] tag.  Any other 3D tags would be useless meta-tags, and as such are not welcome.

Comment: @MBraedley Glad to hear we already have that(I didn't realize I was on meta site so it wasn't showing up for me when I searched).  That second sentence is useless and not welcome, just as my second sentence is useless and not welcome.